AbpFramework Publish Error, HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid
I am developing an app using [abp] framework. But I am having trouble publishing AuthServer. I Publish AuthServer then i wanted to see on local IIS. I uploaded certificate that is necessary. when i wanted to browse website on browser, i faced this error ** HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.**
My Appsettings and IIS Binding settings are below.
AppSettings
IIS Bindings
I have tried, I clonned a pure application of AbpFramework and i could Publish it. I saw on browser, it works well.
Websites that i got help are below;
https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/startup-templates/application/deployment-iis?UI=MVC&DB=EF&Tiered=Yes
https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#installation

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 400 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@samwu, Hey,thanks for reply,  I check logs C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2 here and I see that -> https://auth.sample/ 400 0 0 1
2024-04-16 06:56:06 127.0.0.1 GET / - 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/123.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 400 0 0 1723
No more details here. Also  C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles is empty. I enabled  failed request tracing btw ın iis .

These messages are unable to analyze your problem, you can refer to the content in this link to enable failed request tracking: Troubleshoot failed requests using tracing in IIS.
